# Using log4net as a class library?

Tags: c#, log4net, app-config

I'm working with a console application with c#, visual studio 2008, .net framework 3.5, windows 7. I've created a log4net library and plan to use it on several projects on my solution.

This is how my log4net library class looks like:

```
public class LibraryLogClass1
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public static void Method3(string message)
    {
        log.Debug(message);
    }
}
```

In my main console project I have this:

```
   class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LibraryLog3.LibraryLogClass1.Method3("test3");
        }
    }
```

I've added this line in my AssemblyInfo.cs in my console project:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

This is my App.config in my console project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <file value="C:\test3.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

When I ran the program the file is not created.

How can I solve this?

thanks

Comment: What do you expect the name of the file to be? Where do you expect it to be located? Have you looked in your entire project directory (including subdirectories) for log files to see if it it was named something you didn't expect? Is it possible that the call to `log.Debug` threw an exception that your program squashed without letting you see it?

Comment: @JimMischel hi Jim. As you can see i've added this line on the App.config: **<file value="C:\test3.txt"/>**. So I've looked at that path but the file is not there. I've looked in the project directory and subdirectories but there was nothing there............if indeed log.Debug threw an exception how can I look for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [log4net documentation for assembly attributes](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes) it says this:

"Therefore if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net
to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to LogManager.GetLogger will cause the attributes on the **calling assembly** 
to be read and processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and
certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked.**"

In your case, your call to Method3 is loading the library assembly, so the static field is attempting to load attributes from the library log class, where the attributes aren't defined.

I generally have something like this at the start of my main program:

```
LogManager.GetLogger("Initialise log4net from the current assembly attributes");
```